# why One-To-Many association cannot be Bidirectional and it should just be Unidirectional?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, oop, associations

I'm trying to learn about `JPA` and `Hibernate` and I was trying to learn about some database terms.

In [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nf1vwRpHNW0) on youtube, the teacher (at 2:42) said:

> One-To-Many is only Unidirectional.

and she said suppose thsese two class:

```
class Person {

    List<Address> addresses;

}


class Address {

    Person p;

}
```

and she said:

> this is One-To-Many. but Address cannot have a collection of Person
> because if it has a collection of Person, it's going to be
> Many-To-Many.

but I think she is not right, because we can have these two:

```
thePerson.getAddresses().get(i);
```

and

```
anAddress.getPerson();
```

When we can have these two statements, then it is **Bidirectional**. Then why she said it can be just **Unidirectional**?

What is **Bidirectional's** exact definition with which she came to such a conclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, any relationship can be **unidirectional** or **bidirectional**, it's all depend on how you want to display or retrieve your data, and your business rules.

> When we can have these two statements, then it is Bidirectional. Then
> why she said it can be just Unidirectional?

There is also a big mismatch between the `object oriented` approach of `ORMs` like `Hibernate` and how tables and relationships are defined in a `relational database`. She can be wright, because, in the point of view of a database, relationships are by default **unidirectional**.

The difference between **unidirectional** and **bidirectional** is defined by the fact that ***you can access the records of the other side of your relationship from where you are***.

> What is Bidirectional's exact definition with which she came to such a
> conclusion?

In your example we can interpret your relationship like this:

- **Unidirectional**: you can get all your addresses from person, but not the inverse

  ```
   class Person {

       @OneToMany
       List<Address> addresses;

   }

   class Address {

       // Here you don't add the ManyToOne
       Person p;
   }
  ```
- **Bidirectional**: you can get all your addresses from person and get a person from an address

  ```
   class Person {

       @OneToMany
       List<Address> addresses;
   }

   class Address {

       @ManyToOne
       Person p;
   }
  ```

Take a look at those links below:

[Difference between unidirectional and bidirectional relational relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672064/difference-between-unidirectional-and-bidirectional-relational-relationship)

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships

[What is Object/Relational mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305464/what-is-object-relational-mismatch)

Comment: Harry when for those two class, we provide all of the Getters, then we have always bidirectional. right?

Comment: @TomWard no, as soon as you define an annotation in both classes, they are bidirectional. Those annotations should be taken in the point of view of Hibernate and Java. It helps the framework to know how to manage and retrieve your data.

Comment: no I mean just in OOP world and without hibernate and jpa. if we provide all of the Getters, then we have always bidirectional. right? I'm confused. because with ```thePerson.getAddresses().get(i);``` and ```anAddress.getPerson();``` I see it is Bidirectional. just with providing Getters for both sides.

Comment: @TomWard yes in OOP world this also means you relationship is bidirectional.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, she's not right. All kinds of relationships can de unidirectional or bidirectional.

On the child side, you have to annotate the field with @JoinColumn.

On the parent side, you have to use the property mappedBy of @OneToMany annotation.

Example:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private List<Address> addresses;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private User user;
```

Here's a good lecture about it.

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/